# Increase a variable in subquery in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a query in SQL:

```
 DECLARE @c int=0, @technicalProperty nvarchar(max)=''

    set  @technicalProperty+=
     (
      SELECT DISTINCT
                                     '<div class="col-12 ms-3 ms-md-0 mt-3">
                                       <label for="inputState" class="form-label">'+ec.Title+':</label>
                                       <ul class="" id="inputState'+CAST(@c as nvarchar(max))+'">
                                       '+STUFF(
                                          ( 
                                             SELECT '  <li class="btn btn-outline-dark me-3 my-1" data-spec1="'+CAST(dy.categoryParentID as nvarchar(max))+'" data-spec2="'+CAST(dy.CategoryChildID as nvarchar(max))+'" data-oldproid="'+CAST(@current_CommodityNServicePropertyID as nvarchar(max))+'" style="width:120px;">'+dy.childTitle+'</li>'
                                             FROM #dynamicTbl dy
                                             WHERE dy.CategoryParentID =ec.categoryParentID
                                             FOR XML PATH(''),TYPE
                                          ).value('.','NVARCHAR(MAX)'),1,1,'')
                                        +'</ul></div>'  
      
       FROM CnSTechnicalSpecification sc
       LEFT JOIN categoryParent ec on ec.categoryParentID=sc.categoryParentID
       WHERE CategoryChildID=@ChildID 
          and ec.categoryParentID!=3
       FOR XML PATH(''),TYPE).value('.','nvarchar(max)')
```

I want to increase `@c` variable when every time I run the sub-query. I used this variable in `id="inputState'+CAST(@c as nvarchar(max))+` is there any solution?

Comment: How is the `@c` variable defined? What datatype?

Comment: @marc_s @c variable data type is int.